# Intercepting incoming messages in Spring Rabbitmq with xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I need to intercept every incoming message from RabbitMQ, extract some specific headers from it and put it into thread context. I see different solutions on the internet but they are used with code configuration while i have xml configuration and can't change it.
This is my configuration:

```
<bean id="eventPublisherService"
        class="...">
    ...
  </bean>

  <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                             host="${queuing.connection.host}" virtual-host="${queuing.connection.virtualHost}"
                             username="${queuing.connection.username}" password="${queuing.connection.password}"/>

  <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>


  <rabbit:queue name="${some.queue}"/>
  ... more queues

  <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"
                   connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel-transacted="true"/>

  <bean id="mailingConsumer" class="..."/>
  ... more beans

  <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" advice-chain="retryAdvice">
    <rabbit:listener ref="mailingConsumer" queue-names="${...}" id="mailingConsumerId"/>
    ... more listeners
  </rabbit:listener-container>
```

I tried to use MessagePostProcessor but I'm not sure how to integrate it into this existing setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. The `<rabbit:listener-container>` does not expose a property for the `setAfterReceivePostProcessors()`.

You can achieve that, thought, via `advice-chain`. I see you already set a `retryAdvice`. So, implement a `MethodInterceptor` and set a desired thread context before calling `invocation.proceed()`.

You may consider to use `ListenerContainerFactoryBean` as a `<bean>` definition instead of that `<rabbit:listener-container>`.